# DNS resolution loggin on Windows

Tags: active-directory, dns, windows-server-2008

like to see all DNS queries received by DNS server. Is there is any way to log all of these on windows DNS server?

Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

There is a logging option on one of the tabs of the DNS server's properties in the MMC. Be careful - it will generate a ton of data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interestedd in seeing what was queried, but not when or by whom, turn on the advanced view in the DNS MMC. Then you can look in the "Cached Lookup" zone, which is where all queries are cached untill thier TTLs expire.

If you need to know more, you could start WireShark on the DNS server with a capture filter.  There you will see, what was queried, when and from what IP address.

Hope that helps.